# Is $\Bbb E [XN|N=n] =\Bbb E[nX]$?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

It seems obvious that the statement is true, but I was unable to prove it from the definitions.

In general, I would like to show something like "For a function of two random variables $f(X,N)$ we have $$\Bbb E [f(X,N)|N=n] =\Bbb E[f(X,n)]$$"
For a conditional expectation we need a conditional probability density. Letting $Y=f(X,N)$ for brevity, we have to find $f_{Y|N}(y|n)=\frac{f_{Y,N}(y,n)}{f_N(n)}$.

However, I do not know how to compute this conditional density. I tried computing the cumulative density function as $F_{Y,N} (y,n)=\Bbb P (Y<y,N<n)$ but that did not work either because at most I only know that $N<n$, which is insufficient to transform $\Bbb P (Y<y,N<n)$ to $\Bbb P (X<\frac yn, N<n)$. 

Then I tried simply plugging into the integral formula in the definition, but there I would have to integrate with respect to $y=xn$, and I am confused on how to deal with the $n$. 

In short, I do not know how to prove that, for random variables $X,N$ $$\Bbb E [f(X,N)|N=n] =\Bbb E[f(X,n)]$$
If the statement is false or it requires stronger assumptions or it can be proven more generally/cleanly using measure theory I am all ears.

Comment: It is not true in general. $X$ and $N$ must be independent. What is true in general is that $$ E(f(X,N)\mid N=n) = E(f(X,n)\mid N = n).$$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen and how would you prove that?

Comment: How about we go a bit easier and try $E(f(N)\mid N=n) = E(f(n)\mid N=n)?$ To do this via conditional distributions, you need the joint distribution of $N$ and itself (I'll do the discrete case here). Well, $$P(N=n,N=m) = \delta_{n,m}P(N=m).$$ So, we have $$P(N=n\mid N=m) = \frac{\delta_{n,m}P(N=m)}{P(N=m} = \delta_{m,n}$$ (this should make a lot of intuitive sense). And then $E(f(N)\mid N=n) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty f(k) \delta_{k,n} = f(n).$ Similarly $E(f(n)\mid N=n) =f(n)E(1\mid N=n)=f(n)\sum_{k=1}^\infty \delta_{k,n} = f(n).$ Now try letting $X$ come along for the ride.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen so the probability density function I have to calculate is $f_{X,N|N}$ instead of $f_{XN|N}$?

Comment: To do it like I did it you'd calculate the joint of $X,N$ and $N$ again, getting $P(X=x,N=n\mid N=m) = P(X=x\mid N=m)\delta_{m,n}$ I'd avoid continuous variables (at least $N$) here since conditioning on events with zero probability is tricky.